# Duplicates in column: randomly keep one

Tags: bash, awk, duplicates, multiple-columns

I have a file (`input.txt`) with a structure similar to this:

```
 abc    1
 bcd    a
 cde    1
 def    4
 efg    a
 fgh    3
```

I want to remove duplicates in column 2, in order to have only unique strings in that column (independently to what is in column 1). But the chosen line should be **selected aleatory**. The output could *for example* be:

```
 bcd    a
 cde    1
 def    4
 fgh    3
```

I tried to create a file listing the duplicates (using `awk '{print $2}' input.txt | sort | uniq -D | uniq`) but then I only managed to remove them all with `awk '!A[$2]++'` instead of randomly keeping one of the duplicates.

Comment: What's the problem with `awk '!A[$2]++' file`

Comment: If in column 2 there is a duplicate, `awk '!A[$2]++' file` removes the line. But I want to keep one occurence of the duplicate in the file (in a random way).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pre-process the input to randomize it:

```
shuf input.txt | awk '!A[$2]++'
```

Comment: ^1 very nice approach!

Comment: So simple and it works perfectly fine. Thank you @William!

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for true multi-dimensional arrays:

```
$ awk '{a[$2][++cnt[$2]]=$0} END{srand(); for (k in a) print a[k][int(rand()*cnt[k])+1]}' file
 efg    a
 cde    1
 fgh    3
 def    4
```

With other awks:

```
$ awk '{keys[$2]; a[$2,++cnt[$2]]=$0} END{srand(); for (k in keys) print a[k,int(rand()*cnt[k])+1]}' file
 bcd    a
 abc    1
 fgh    3
 def    4
```

Answer (score 1):

With `perl`

```
$ perl -MList::Util=shuffle -e 'print grep { !$seen{(split)[1]}++ } shuffle <>' input.txt
 def    4
 fgh    3
 bcd    a
 abc    1
```

- `-MList::Util=shuffle` to get `shuffle` function from `List::Util` module
- `shuffle <>` here `<>` would get all input lines as array and then gets shuffled
- `grep { !$seen{(split)[1]}++ }` to filter lines based on 2nd field of each array element based on whitespace as separator

With `ruby`

```
$ ruby -e 'puts readlines.shuffle.uniq {|s| s.split[1]}' input.txt
 abc    1
 bcd    a
 fgh    3
 def    4
```

- `readlines` will get all lines from input file as array
- `shuffle` to randomize the elements
- `uniq` to get unique elements

  - `{|s| s.split[1]}` based on 2nd field value, using whitespace as separator
- `puts` to print the array elements